# Is it possible to capture Android phone SIM card APDUs?

Tags: android, logging, smartcard, apdu, sim-card

I want to know are there any methods to log/trace APDUs which is communicated between SIM and Android Phone (ME)?

I want to log APDUs which transferred during the mobile network handshake process.

Comment: I would assume, that you will achieve meaningful results faster, if you simply look up "network authentication" in the GSM specifications.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any software method to do this.

There is a [Simtrace 2](https://osmocom.org/projects/simtrace2) under Osmocom project which provides a hardware based logger:

> Osmocom SIMtrace 2 is a software, firmware and hardware system for passively tracing SIM-ME communication between the SIM card and the mobile phone, and remote SIM operation.
> While it was designed for SIM-ME communication, it supports all ISO 7816 smart-cards using the T=0 protocol (the most common case).

Good luck with your project!